# iOS app when in background causing safari pages to appear black

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, swiftui

I am creating an iOS app using SwiftUI and a wrapper class.

The app uses a pageViewController to swipe through a deck of cards.  When I run the app and swipe through many cards quickly back and forth, occasionally after switching to safari the safari pages appear black.  The navigation bar of safari and footer appear normally but all content is black.

If I kill my app, safari immediately returns to normal.  It does not appear to effect any other app.  It seems like an element of my app is not being removed from the window and covering the content of safari?  As implausible as that seems.  The only other thing I can think of would be excess memory usage of my app in background.  However my app has no processes running in background mode.

I really have no idea where to start trouble shooting this issue.  I am using the following code for the wrapper:

```
struct ContentViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ContentViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContentViewControllerWrapper>) -> ContentViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {
        return ContentViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ContentViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContentViewControllerWrapper>) {
    }
}
```

And when I enter my app I use the following:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to manually disconnect the scene when the app enters background mode?  I couldn't see any reference to doing that.

It may also be that it's not to do with SwiftUI and scenes but then I have not seen any other cases of this happening to others.

This is what my safari page looks like:

[image]

I have just had another occurrence in a different app.  With my app running in background, the photos app crashes when I select a picture to display.  It works fine until I select the actual picture and it tries to transition to it after which it crashes.

So it may be a navigation issue caused by my app.

Comment: More likely is that your app is using a lot of memory.  Check the memory use indicator in Xcode and use the Leaks instrument

Comment: you were exactly right.  the pageViewController was constantly instantiating new viewControllers that were not being deallocated due to strong references.  I used the allocations instrument to figure that out thanks to your suggestion.  When I made those references 'weak' the viewControllers were deallocated correctly and all the issues went away.  So it was a memory issue.  I will be happy to mark it as correct if you want to change your comment to an answer.  thx.